# Should junior-programmer and junior tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-merge

Should [junior-programmer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior-programmer) and [junior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior) tags be merged?

I think so. I would like to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done, since it just made sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Thomas.